# Android Studio 3.0 Unresolved reference: SupportedLanguages for AIConfiguration class in Dialogflow(api.ai)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialogflow-es

I am building a chatbot Android app in Kotlin, through queries to a Dialogflow agent. I am using the [Dialogflow android client github repository](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client) Readme and the [sample app](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client/tree/master/apiAISampleApp) provided in that repository as the basis to build the app. As referenced in the above sources, java code for `AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages` works fine:

```
import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;
.....
private void initService(final LanguageConfig selectedLanguage) {
final AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages lang = AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.fromLanguageTag(selectedLanguage.getLanguageCode());
.....
```

You can find the full usage of this [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client/blob/master/apiAISampleApp/src/main/java/ai/api/sample/AIServiceSampleActivity.java).

When I am implementing this in Kotlin:

```
import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration
....
    private fun initService() {
        //final AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages lang = AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.fromLanguageTag(selectedLanguage.getLanguageCode());
        val config = AIConfiguration(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.EnglishGB,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System)
....
```

in Android 3.0 I am getting a gradle error of "**Unresolved reference: SupportedLanguages**" for `AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages`. `AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine` is resolving just fine. Why is this problem happening? What solution/work-around can I implement?

My higher level `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    compile 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'
    //compile project(':ailib')

    application project(':app')
    feature project(':chatbot')
}
```

My module `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':base')

    //add the google gson library
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
```

Comment: calling `ai.api.android.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages` in Java works fine as above. In Kotlin 1 solution I found for the above code is to use `ai.api.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages` in the code, which resolved correctly. But `ai.api.android.AIConfiguration` implements `ai.api.AIConfiguration`, so why this issue arises at all I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround I found that is working is to use `ai.api.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages` which is resolving instead of `ai.api.android.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages` which is not resolving in kotlin in Android Studio 3.0 as mentioned in the question.

However, calling `ai.api.android.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages` works just fine in Java code, in which case it is resolving correctly in Android Studio 3.0. Since `ai.api.android.AIConfiguration` implements `ai.api.AIConfiguration`, why this issue is arising is puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line instead of previous -

> ai.api.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,